# Does an oscilloscope connected to the terminals of the secondary coil of a transformer count as a 'closed circuit'

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

What I mean by this is: is there an energy transfer between the two coils? Does current flow in the secondary coil circuit?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the oscilloscope - you need to find out the input impedance of the oscilloscope, and this impedance is then [reflected](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80929/reflecting-impedance-in-a-transformer) to the primary. Given the input impedance, you can calculate the current flow and power transfer that happens.

Common oscilloscope impedances are in the megaohm range, but sometimes oscilloscopes are made with impedances matched to the characteristic impedance of microwave lines to prevent reflexions in high speed microwave circuits. So $50\Omega$ is common for microwave oscilloscopes.